# solving inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Was asked to solve $x^2 < 81$ and write answer in interval notation.

I just wanted to  refresh myself but the answer we get is $x < \pm 9$ so the interval notation would be $(-\infty, 9)$?

Answer (score 3):

No because $(-10)^2\gt 81$ It should be $(-9,9)$

You should have absolute signs on $|x|\lt 9$ that way you won't confuse yourself with the $-9$ on the right.

Comment: $-10^2$ is ambiguous - you might want to write that as $(-10)^2$...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  Good point.  I would say it is not ambiguous, it is wrong.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

no, $-9<x<9$

Once you times a negative number to the equality, the direction of sign is reversed.

Answer (score 2):

$x^2<81$ implies $x^2-81<0$ implies $(x-9)(x+9)<0$ therefore:

either ( $x-9<0$ and $x+9>0$ ) or ( $x-9>0$ and  $x+9<0$ which is an impossible case).
therefore

$-9<x<9$ , $x \in (-9,9)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x| = d(x, 0)$ for any real number $x$.
So if you wish to solve $x^2 < 81$, this is equivalent to 
$|x| < 9$, or $-9 < x < 9.$

Answer (score 0):

I like to think of the graph of $y=x^2$ and the graph of $y=81$. The part of the parabola under the line is the part from -9 to 9.